# Django - Upload Files, Display using template tags

Tags: html, django, file-upload, django-templates

I am trying to create my first custom template tag.
My model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from audiofield.fields import AudioField

# Create your models here.
class Musikk(models.Model):
    tittel = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = "Skriv tittel her")
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = "Artist")
    cover = models.FileField("Cover", upload_to="audio/")
    audio = AudioField(upload_to="audio/", blank=True, ext_whitelist=(".mp3",".wav",".ogg")) 
    is_active = models.BooleanField(("is active"), default = False)
    date_created = models.DateField(verbose_name="Created on date", auto_now_add="True")

class MusikkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    list_display = ('tittel', 'artist', 'cover', 'audio', 'is_active', 'date_created')
```

My settings.py like this:

```
# Media files
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My template tag (musikk_tag.py) looks like this:

```
from django import template
from .. import models

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_musikk_tags():
    return models.Musikk.objects.all()
```

I do get to render the 'title' and 'artist' from the model into my html, but not my 'cover' and 'audio'.

Somehow the file is not uploaded to /media/. Please help me figure out whats wrong!

Comment: What have you set up to actually serve files from MEDIA_URL?

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean, but I serve django on my localhost

Comment: That really wasn't what I asked. MEDIA_URL is just a setting; you need to actually set something up to serve files on that URL. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

Comment: In my urls.py: `(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),`